# XSLT hide element IF string is empty

Tags: xslt

I want to hide "imageText" and the div IF string is empty. At the moment, this imageText overlays text onto an image with a background color (the text is specified in Umbraco).

I've already tried:

```
<xsl:if test = "imageText" != ''">
```

Could someone please help me accomplish this?

Here's my code:

```
<td width="300" height="114" valign="top">

    <div class="imageTitle">
    <xsl:call-template name="getText">
      <xsl:with-param name="imageText" select="$bottomImageLeftText" />
    </xsl:call-template>   
    </div>

    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the text in an element called `imageText` or is it in a variable called `$bottomImageLeftText`?  It seems like the latter, so please try this:

```
<td width="300" height="114" valign="top">
  <xsl:if test="$bottomImageLeftText != ''">
    <div class="imageTitle">
      <xsl:call-template name="getText">
        <xsl:with-param name="imageText" select="$bottomImageLeftText" />
      </xsl:call-template>   
    </div>
  </xsl:if>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to condition on the value you would be passing to the `with-param`, not the parameter name (which is only meaningful *inside* the called template). So wrap the `div` element in a

```
<xsl:if test="string($bottomImageLeftText)">
```

This will include the div and its contents if the string value of `$bottomImageLeftText` is non-empty - which includes the case where it contains only whitespace. If you want to treat whitespace-only the same as completely empty you can use

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space($bottomImageLeftText)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
<!-- Code which calls the getText template and passes the bottomImageLeftText variable -->
<xsl:call-template name="getText">
  <xsl:with-param name="imageText" select="$bottomImageLeftText" />
</xsl:call-template>

<!-- getText template which checks the param imageText for an empty string. -->
  <xsl:template name="getText" >
    <xsl:param name="imageText" />

    <xsl:if test="$imageText" >
      <div class="imageTitle">
        <!-- your code, display image title -->
      </div>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```